# Saving files to another DocumentRoot using PHP

Tags: php, apache, open-basedir

I have a site that generates some image files. Instead of saving to within the site's `DocumentRoot` like `\home\mysite\public_html\photos`, I want to save to another user's directory like `\home\anothersite\public_html\photos`. The reason for doing this is to facilitate a move of all photos to its own dedicated server just for serving images.

Is there a way for PHP to save a file to another user's directory? I am thinking of using `rename()` and disabling `open_basedir`. Or should I use `ftp_fput()`?

---

### Update

When I try this (which involves `mkdir()` to create new directories), I get the error:

```
mkdir() [function.mkdir]: Permission denied
```

Did I miss out on some permission settings?

Comment: As long as you have write permissions, you can save it exactly the same way as you are doing now / in the current directory. PHP does not care about the document root of the web-server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save it exactly the same way as you are doing now / in the current directory. PHP does not care about the document root of the web-server

Answer by Jeron.